# Why are my graphics degraded when I load my Form at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have made a winform application for use within the company I work for( web site was not an option)
The user base of this application has increased and of course it has become a pain to upgrade everyone...even more now since users are now disallowed form installing their own applications.

I came up with the idea of keeping the application stored on a database to be loaded upon execution.
It all works fine, but it seems that the graphics have a pre-windows7 (on win7 machines) look to them. Why would that be happening?

```
      System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
      Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
      Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
      Application.Run(form);
```

Comment: Do you call `Application.EnableVisualStyles` before any controls are created, prior to loading the assembly?

Comment: that seems to have done it...thank you

Comment: On a related note, when you mention that users don't have permissions to install their own applications and upgrading it a problem you might want to look at ClickOnce. It works well in low privilege environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `Application.EnableVisualStyles` before any controls are created, prior to loading the assembly.

Comment: Fascinating that you were able to deduce that from "graphics degraded".

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you kind sir. The give-away was *but it seems that the graphics have a pre-windows7 (on win7 machines) look to them*